# How to display the last item in the database using textbox

Tags: vb.net

I need to get the last row in my db table I managed to get the last rowusing combobox. But I want to get it without using combobox and I want to display it in a textbox. Can some one help me?

```
      Dim lastitem As Integer = 0
    lastitem = ClassInfo.ComboBox1.Items.Count
    ClassInfo.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = lastitem - 1
```

Comment: The order that the DB stores things is largely irrelevant.  Typically you would either specify the order in your SQL or select a specific one based on  the characteristic of one or more *data elements*....such as: add a `LastUpdatedDate` or `DateAdded` column and select the MAX of that column

Comment: My items has an ID. so I guess the order is ASC.  its the same as mycombobox.  The arrangement doesnt matter I just want to get the last value of the lastrow just like what I did in the combobox. Can you provide me a sample code? i have no idea on how to achieve this .thanks mate

Comment: I dont. its my PK and Its AC. so the order is asc.

Comment: `i have no idea on how to...` means you need to do more research.  SQL does more than `SELECT *`...its a whole language itself.  Sounds like you (think that you) need the MAX id

Comment: Thanks mate. I need to surf more I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by the index, that is responsible for the property of being first or last or whatever, in decreasing order and just take the first (e.g. by calling `.First()` on your (ordered) collection)

Edit: if you using SQL than it would be something like

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourfilter
ORDER BY yoursignificantindex DESC
```